# Twitter API check for NSFW content

Tags: twitter

In the [Twitter Api](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) is there anything in the response that tells if the Tweet has been flagged as NSFW or inappropriate? The response is quite big but I couldn't find anything in it that flags the Tweet as NSFW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `possibly_sensitive` flag in the Twitter API, [tweet object](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets).

> possibly_sensitive    Boolean Nullable. This field only surfaces when a
>   tweet contains a link. The meaning of the field doesn’t pertain to the
>   tweet content itself, but instead it is an indicator that the URL
>   contained in the tweet may contain content or media identified as
>   sensitive content.

Example:

```
"possibly_sensitive":true
```